# Hook WSO2 logging service

Tags: logging, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm working on WSO2 ESB 4.8.1.
I need to write a logging client able to print all wso2carbon.log rows.
I ve seen that on wso2 esb console there's the system log section in which i can read all the log information. Is it possibile to hook the same wso2 service designated to print the log in order to print the same log lines in a custom text area?

Comment: what u mean by a custom text area? do you wanna get the logs on the fly to some other program?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to display the system log on a custom application

Comment: Can't you just read the wso2carbon.log file from ur app?

Comment: yes it's a possibility... but maybe it could bring some access permission problem. So i was wondering: if wso2 web console does it... why cannot i?

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 Carbon Console (Mgt console) reads log lines from a log4j memory appender. It reads logEvents from the memory and display it in the carbon console. You can do two things. If you want to write your logs to a specific location directly then you can use a log4j Appender Or else you can get the logevents from an already existing location.

If you are writing your own appender please make sure you use log4j 1.2.X manual when writing/picking your appender as WSO2 do not support log4j 2.X (which has more advance set of appenders) yet.

[1] https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Answer (score 0):

"print all wso2carbon.log rows" is a bit ambiguous requirement. I think your problem can be solved by using a Log4j Appender[1], with maybe a JDBC or a JMS[2] destination and read from there to whatever interface you're trying to display logs in.

[1] - https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

[2] - http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq.html